# Open recorded video in UIImagePickerController

Tags: ios, swift, uiimagepickercontroller

I'm creating a custom overlay to use with UIImagePickerController as I'd like to modify the text and image that comes as the default controls. This is part is displayed as needed.

I'd like to keep the user flow as close to the default as possible. I'd like to have the video playable after it has been captured, but I'm unsure how to open it within the UIImagePickerController.

I have the video data in the `videoData` variable but am unsure how to proceed. Do I save this to a class level variable and instantiate a new imagePickerController or do I need to segue to a completely new view controller and construct the UI from scratch. The reason for this is that the user may need to re-record the video.

```
func imagePickerController(picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String : AnyObject]){

    // Save video to device
    let videoURL = info[UIImagePickerControllerMediaURL] as! NSURL
    let videoData = NSData(contentsOfURL: videoURL)

    self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
}
```

Any help much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `AVPlayer` to play video;

```
func imagePickerController(picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String : AnyObject]){

    // Save video to device
    let videoURL = info[UIImagePickerControllerMediaURL] as! NSURL

    // no need NSData
    //let videoData = NSData(contentsOfURL: videoURL)

    self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)

    let videoPlayer = AVPlayer(URL: videoURL)
    videoPlayer.actionAtItemEnd = .None
    let videoLayer = AVPlayerLayer(player: videoPlayer)
    videoLayer.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 200, 200)
    self.view.layer.addSublayer(videoLayer)
    videoPlayer.play()
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I was hoping to keep the user within the UIImagePickerController incase they want to re record the video.

Comment: I used this as a basis for an answer, combined with a UIImagePicker overlay for a consistent UI. Many thanks for my jumping off point.